# My parallax website is lagging on chrome i create using React.js,three.js

Tags: freeze, parallax, lag

i make portfolio https://zippy-pie-a4cb51.netlify.app/
website and deploy it on netlify but why my website is lagging on chrome browser even My website is not lagging on any other browser.

am using React.vite , three.js , scss and framermotion

tell me any solution that tell me any solution so that my project does not hang on chrome